# Is there any way to do lapply for patternmatch function?

Tags: r, python-3.x, awk, pattern-matching

I am trying to index my substring with the reference string. The substring has 1 or 2 mismatches.

```
   substr   Ref
1 CTTGTAGG  AGGCCTTGTCGGT
2 TATGACT   ATTTATGATTGC
```

I want to get something like

```
    substr   Ref         substr_start
1 CTTGTAGG  AGGCCTTGTCGGT 5            
2 TATGACT   ATTTATGATTGC  4
```

R matchPattern function from Biostrings works fine. But I want to run it through loop or lapply to get the outcome for all entries in the file.

Here is what I have tried:

```
for(i in 1:length(file$substr)){
for(j in 1:length(file$Ref)){
matchPattern(file$substr[i], file$Ref[j], max.mismatch=1, min.mismatch=0, with.indels=FALSE, fixed=TRUE, algorithm="auto") 
}}
```

it Just throws an error saying "unable to find an inherited method for function ‘matchpattern’ for signature ‘factor’"

Is there any good way to do this? Solutions outside of  R are also welcome :)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not really understand your question completely. What do you mean with the mismatches?

Comment: If you see my example, my substr is not a perfect match. In that context, I need to allow one mismatch in the substr to match it with the reference sequence. it's kind of local alignment with one mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `mapply` to apply `matchPattern` to every `substr` and `Ref` value in `file` and return `start` value.

```
library(Biostrings)

file$substr_start <- mapply(function(x, y) {
         temp <- matchPattern(x, y, max.mismatch=1, min.mismatch=0, 
                  with.indels=FALSE, fixed=TRUE, algorithm="auto")
         start(temp)
}, file$substr, file$Ref)


file
#    substr           Ref substr_start
#1 CTTGTAGG AGGCCTTGTCGGT            5
#2  TATGACT  ATTTATGATTGC            4
```

Comment: It is giving the same error Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘matchPattern’ for signature ‘"factor"’

Comment: @Biofreek Run `file[] <- lapply(file, as.character)` first.

Comment: Also is there a way to get the best match. I have noticed that with smaller substrings there are multiple matches, in which case I would prefer the ones with no mismatch.

Comment: I don't know much about `Biostrings` package, probably you can ask it as a new question.